# Error Occuring when using LEFT / MID Functions to Isolate Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the LEFT and MID functions on the following Cells to isolate the number for comparison.

"3 Month" -> LEFT(A1,1) -> 3

"R2S: 10 Month" -> MID(A2,6,2) -> 10

The problem is, when I compare these two resulting numbers it does not work. A simple IF(A1<A2,,) is returning as false. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `LEFT` and `MID` return *strings*, not *numerics*. Coerce the results of your functions to numerics with a suitable operation or function, of which there are many.

Comment: Did you try changing them to as a number like, : `IF(LEFT(A1)+0<MID(A2,6,2)/1,,)` ???

Comment: The function `VALUE()` also converts string to numeric. E.g. `VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))`

Comment: Thanks all, VALUE() worked.